# Infinitely differentiable Fourier series imply uniformly convergent

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, fourier-series

Consider the following multiple Fourier series $f(x_1,...,x_N)=\sum_m a^me^{2\pi i(m_1x_1+...+m_{N}x_{N})}$ where $m=(m_1,...,m_{N})$ is an integers vector. Moreover, suppose that $f$ is an infinitely differentiable function.

> Then is it true that the series is uniformly convergent?

It seems to be true but I cannot find a good reference online about multiple Fourier series.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. It works exactly the same way when $N= 1$ : the Fourier series of $f''(x) $ is $\sum_m a_m (2i \pi m)^2 e^{2i \pi m x}$ (we don't know yet if it converges) where $a_m (2i \pi m)^2 = \int_0^1 f''(x)e^{-2i \pi m x}dx \le \int_0^1 |f''(x)|dx= C$ where $C$ is finite since you assume $f$ is $C^\infty$ thus $C^2$. Therefore for $ m\ne 0$ : $|a_m| \le \frac{C}{4 \pi^2 m^2}$ and $\sum_m a_m e^{2i \pi m x}$ converges absolutely and uniformly.

---

For $N > 1$ you can look at the partial $2^{N}$-th derivatives $\prod_{j=1}^N \partial_{x_j}^2 f$ to obtain $|a_m |  \le \frac{C}{\prod_{j=1}^N |m_j|^2}$ where $C = \int_{[0,1]^N} |\partial_{x_j}^2 f(x)|dx$ so that $\sum_{m \in \mathbb{Z}^N} a_m e^{2i \pi \langle m, x \rangle}$ converges absolutely.

---

Note smooth and $1$-periodic is not the same as smooth on $(0,1)$ and $1$-periodic, in the second case $a_m (2i \pi m)^2 = \int_0^1 f''(x)e^{-2i \pi m x}dx$ is not true.

Comment: So you are saying that if $N>1$ then $f_{ij}$ infinitely differentiable implies not only uniform convergence but also absolute convergence of the Fourier series? Do you have some reference about it to suggest?

Comment: @Blacksmith What I wrote is in any course  on Fourier series. It works the same way for $N=1$ and $ N > 1$.

Comment: Sorry but how can you say that the Fourier series of $f''(x)$ is $\sum_ma_m(2i\pi m)^2e^{2i\pi m x}$ without knowing uniform convergence?

Comment: @Blacksmith Integrate by parts two times $\int_0^1 f''(x) e^{-2i \pi m x}dx$ using that $f'(0) = f'(1), f(0) = f(1)$. The point is to show $|a_m (2i\pi m)^2| \le \int_0^1 |f''(x)|dx$

Comment: Ah ok thank you. Since you seem confident with this topic, please see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2543748/equivalent-conditions-for-a-fourier-series-to-be-infinitely-differentiable if you like

Comment: Sorry I am having some problems in writing down the integration by parts: should I take $u(x)=f''(x)e^{-2i\pi mx}$ and $v(x)=1$ ?

Comment: No. It is detailed in every course on the Fourier series and in many questions on MSE.

Comment: ah ok, it's just I can't find a good reference online

Comment: Sorry but even looking online it seems to me that to compute the integration by parts I should integrate the series term by term, which is not possible if we do not know it uniformly converges. For example: I need to compute explicitly the integral from 0 to 1 of $f(x)e^{-2\pi m x}$

Comment: @Blacksmith It is clear you didn't understand anything. See http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2012/REUPapers/Cuddy.pdf p.13

Comment: Oh thank you very much, thanks to those notes I got it